# вывод индекса элемента массива в процессе перебора в цикле

Tags: java, массивы

Друзья добрый день. Помогите с такой задачкой. Существует некий двумерный массив `String[][]massiv`, который я должен обработать в методе, а именно:
просуммировать все элементы; создать исключение в случае, если массив больше 4; и создать исключение с указанием индекса элемента в случае, если в массив подана какая то буква, и `parseInt` выдаёт исключение.

Собственно, моя проблема в том, что я могу вывести в консоль ту букву, которая в массиве - а как вывести индекс элемента этой буквы не пойму. прошу помощи.

```
public class Handler {

    Mas mas = new Mas();

    public void doSmthArray() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (mas.getMassiv().length > 4) throw new MyArraySizeException();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.getMassiv().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.getMassiv()[i].length; j++) {
                try {
                    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(mas.getMassiv()[i][j]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println();
                    throw new MyArrayDataException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу прощения господа. Моя проблема в том, что я не умею правильно поставить вопрос. Смысл в том, что мне нужно в моём psvm обработать все перехваченные исключения:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        try {
            handler.doSmthArray();
        }catch (MyArraySizeException e){
            System.out.println("превышен допустимый размер массива");
        }catch (MyArrayDataException exc){

        }
    }
}
```

так вот в самом блоке catch (MyArrayDataException exc) я и должен объявить в консоль инфу - индекс неверного элемента массива massiv. Т.е. как мне передать этот индекс из класса Handler в класс MainClass? Надеюсь сейчас правильно задал вопрос.

Comment: Вы не знаете где взять индексы буквы или есть какая-то другая проблема?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> throw new MyArrayDataException();
> ```

```
throw new MyArrayDataException(i, j);
```

```
class MyArrayDataException extends Exception {
  public MyArrayDataException(int i, int j) {
    super("Error at (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
```

Как-то так...

Answer (score 1):

Так как я понял вы сами создали это исключения, то вы можете расширить свое исключение с помощью например дополнительного конструктора, в котором добавить атрибут конкретного значения. А так же например можно создать геттер для этого значение в своем исключений. А потом его доставать

Answer (score 0):

Если вы вводите значения индексов сами, присвойте их сначала переменным перед выводом значения элемента. А потом что-то типа System.out.println("Index element: [" + i + "][" + j + "]" );

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.log('i = ' + i + ' j = ' + j);
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Comment: Он пишет на Java, а не на JS

Comment: System.out.println('i = ' + i + ' j = ' + j); Общий смысл ведь понятен...

Comment: Вы всегда можете отредактировать свой ответ